# Thunderbird Lightning caldav sync doesn't show any data/events

Tags: calendar, caldav, thunderbird-lightning

when i try to synchronize my caldav server implementation with Thunderbird 45.4.0 and Lightning 4.7.4 (one particular calendar collection) it doesnt show any data or events in the calendar though the last call of the sequence provided the data.

In the Thunderbird error log i can see one error:

```
Zeitstempel: 07.11.16, 14:21:12
Fehler: [calCachedCalendar] replay action failed: null,
uri=http://127.0.0.1:8003/sap/sports/webdav/appsvc/webdav/services/
server.xsjs/cal/_D043133/, result=2147500037, op=[xpconnect wrapped
calIOperation]
Quelldatei:
file:///Users/d043133/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/hfbvuk9f.default/
extensions/%7Be2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103%7D/calendar-
js/calCachedCalendar.js
Zeile: 327
```

the call sequence is as follows (detailed content via gist-links):

1. Propfind [Request](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-01_request_propfind) - [Response](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-01_response_propfind)
2. Options [Request](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-02_request_options) - [Response](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-02_response_options)
3. Propfind [Request](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-03_request_propfind) - [Response](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-03_response_propfind)
4. Report [Request](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-04_request_report) - [Response](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-04_response_report) - [Response Raw](https://gist.github.com/HilmarDemant/6ba124ea473ac7493412421e11c8adf6#file-04_response_report_raw)

The synchronization with other clients like macOS-calendar and ios-calendar works in principle and shows the data. Does anyone has a clue what is going wrong here?

Comment: You should enable `calendar.debug.log` and `calendar.debug.log.verbose` in the config editor (Options > Advanced > General > Config Editor) to get more debug output. You can also step through things and set breakpoints using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Thunderbird

Comment: Hi Philipp, thanks - but the error above comes from the error log already! I have not tried remote debugging yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to find the cause of the above issue by debugging Thunderbird as propsed by Philipp. The Report Response has http status code 200, but as it is a multistatus response Thunderbird/Lightning expects status code 207 ;-)

Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether that is the cause but I can see two incorrect things:

a) Your `<href/>` property has trailing spaces:

```
<d:href>/sap/sports/webdav/appsvc/webdav/services/server.xsjs/cal/_D043133/EVENT%3A070768ba5dd78ff15458f1985cdaabb1.ics
</d:href>
```

b) your `ORGANIZER` property is not a valid URI

```
ORGANIZER:_D043133
```

Comment: thanks - i think the linebreak is due to a post-formatting of the XML (in Eclipse) for better readability. the raw response doesnt contain it. Regarding the ORGANIZER i need to investigate.

Comment: i added Response Raw for the Report call without trailing spaces - also i understood it that way that organizer should be a email-adress according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.3 so they look now like this: ORGANIZER:mailto:_D043133@sapsportsone.hana.ondemand.com - maybe the empty ones are not correct?